# Quicksort using single loop

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The quicksort code below is giving incorrect results.Could anybody tell what is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 30

int b[MAX];

void print(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int party(int a[],int p,int q)
{
    int pivot=a[p]; 
    int t=a[p];  

     a[p]=a[q];  
     a[q]=t;

    int i,j,k,store=p;

    for(i=p;i<=q-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=pivot)
        {
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[store];
         a[store] = t;store++;}
    }

   t = a[store];
   a[store] = a[q];
   a[q] = a[store];

   return store;
}

void quicksort(int a[],int p,int q)
{
    if(p>=q)
    {
       return;
    }

    int r=party(a,p,q);

    quicksort(a,p,r-1);
    quicksort(a,r+1,q);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter No. oF elements for sorting.\n");
    int i,j,k,n;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d\t",i+1);   scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }

    print(b,n);

    quicksort(b,0,n-1);

    print(b,n);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Just spent few minutes and did some basic indentation instead of asking author to do it. I could have put proper variable names but since answerd felt fine.

Comment: Try indention and format for the question. Also try using a debugger

Comment: What error did you get compiling this code?

Comment: No error in compiling , it is runing and giving wrong output.

Comment: I recommend you to debug it and see what happens step by step. And what are the output/input you are expecting/receiving?

Comment: First tell what's wrong please and then downvote. All questions here can't be of good quality. Beginners also use SO.So it would be great if you could help.

Comment: @Rafed Nole, don't mind those ego experts :D check if party function is generating the right output.

Comment: I'd recommand you to choose better variable names and add comments when you are asking for help. Lines such as ` t=a[store];a[store]=a[q];a[q]=a[store];` requires some effort, you should provide a comment or put the code in a function named `swap` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buried in that dreadful code formatting you seem to like is this:

```
t=a[store];a[store]=a[q];a[q]=a[store];
```

Which to sane people looks like this:

```
t=a[store];
a[store]=a[q];
a[q]=a[store];
```

You're setting `a[q]` to the same value it just was, and not swapping anything. It should read:

```
t=a[store];
a[store]=a[q];
a[q]=t;
```

---

Btw, you don't need both low and high indices, you only need a base array address and a length for this algorithm (and a little pointer math, of course):

```
static void swap_int(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int len)
{
    int i=0, pvt=0;

    if (len <=1)
        return;

    for (;i<len;++i)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[len-1])
            swap_int(a+i,a+pvt++);
    }
    swap_int(a+pvt,a+len-1);
    quicksort(a, pvt++);
    quicksort(a+pvt, len-pvt);
}
```

There ya go, It even has the partitioning built in. The pivot should be random-selected, but thats for another day, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake, nothing about sanity though.Be cool on beginners. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RafedNole No worries. Try it with just one length param. you'll be surprised how easily it comes together.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more,please. One length parameter i.e. pass the length of the subarray/initial index each time to party function ?or To quicksort function ?

Comment: @RafedNole posted. take a look.

Comment: Yes its working great. I can't understand its last statement though, calling quicksort by passing it len-pvt .Why len-pvt ?

Comment: @RafedNole That's now many elements are on the other side of the pivot slot. Remember when you send the subsequences of a quicksort to recursion, you don't include the pivot slot. its the one element that is known to be in the correct position. The statement prior sends `a[0`]...`a[pvt-1`] *and* increments `pvt` to skip the pivot slot on the next line. Is worth a debug session with a small (10 or so) out-of-order sequence to see how it works. trust me.

Comment: Well thanks a lot.Fully understood this algorithm, its great that it becomes so easy using length parameter.Thanks again.

Comment: @RafedNole no problem. If you understand pointer math in C, it isn't hard at all to see how it works. glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This was a very silly mistake.

In swapping a[store] and a[q] in the party function :

t=a[store];   a[store]=a[q];   a[q]=a[store];  -----> This is Wrong.

a[q]= t should be the last statement.

Now it works fine. Thanks for the super quick response anyways.